# Can customErrors be overriden by IIS? (7.0)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config

I control the code but not the server and the person at the other end knows as much about IIS as I do.

I have the classic:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

in my root level web.config, but am not seeing error details.  Could the above have been overriden by a setting at the server/application level?

Comment: What do you see instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the reason we weren't seeing error messages was because the `machine.config` file of our dev server had `<deployment retail="true"/>` after being cloned from our production server:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
          <deployment retail="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It needed to be set to false.  Scott Guthrie elaborates on it in his post [Don’t run production ASP.NET Applications with debug=”true” enabled](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Adding handling in the Application_Error event in your global.asax file could do it but that would be under your control, I would imagine.

[Microsoft KB article here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355) gives an example.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: There currently isn't any global.asax file being used.  Thanks for the tip though.